# xcode4 create target stati library

Tags: ios, xcode

hi have a simple project for ipad in xcode4
i added new target "static library" and xcode created correctly scheme e compile profile...but if i try to use this library in main project i obtain this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_StringLibrary", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i think that i need to copy libStringLibrary.a and .h file in my project folder before start compiling...someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to link to the "static library" from your main project.  If you select your project in the project navigator, then select your main target, you should be able to link to your static library from within the Build Phases tab with Link Binary With Libraries.  You may also want to enter in the directory paths for your library headers in Header Search Paths under Build Settings, which will help with code completion.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i found that i need to add my library in "link  binary with libraries". if i add my library in target dependencies this library will be compiled every time i compile main project.

Comment: Yup. I answered off the top of my head and told you the wrong one.  Editing response for posterity.